# remove img tag from string completely with all posible property

Tags: php

I would like to remove img tag completely with any attribute or styling from a string using `preg_replace`

```
$content= "image to remove completely <img src="jem.jpg" style="height:162px; width:397px" />";
```

This is something with in it.

I tried using `preg_replace`, but it didn't work.

```
$content= "image to remove completely <img src="jem.jpg" style="height:162px; width:397px" />";

$content = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", " ", $content );
```

expected output: `image to remove completely`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Comment: FYI, your first line isn't going to work because of the quotes.

Comment: Assuming `$content` is actually a valid string (as mentioned above, the syntax as in the OP is incorrect), that regex pattern should match that tag and the replacement should be working fine, though note that the output would be `image to remove completely  ` (with two spaces at the end).

Comment: Thanks i saw this and correct still the same npt working                                  $content= "image to remove completely <img src='jem.jpg' style='height:162px; width:397px' />";

$content = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", " ", $content );